# What is the "CNA" mentioned in the "Three Days of the Condor"?

Tags: dialogue, three-days-of-the-condor

In *Three Days of the Condor*, there's a scene where Robert Redford's character calls someone on the phone and requests a "CNA". Does anyone know what CNA stands for in this context?

```
    WOMAN'S VOICE
    (FILTER)
    CNA, Mrs. Coleman speaking.
    TURNER
    (into test-set)
    This is Harold Thomas, Mrs. Coleman,
    Customer Service.  CNA on 202 555-7389,
    please.
    WOMAN'S VOICE
    (FILTER)
    One moment, please.
```

[Source](http://www.awesomefilm.com/script/ThreeDaysoftheCondor.pdf)

(Here's a transcript of the scene in question: http://www.cswap.com/1975/Three_Days_of_the_Condor/cap/en/25fps/a/01_25)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relevant extract of the script:

> Customer service, requesting a CNA...
>   on 202-227-0098.
>   One moment, please.
>   That would be a Mr. Leonard Atwood.
>   365 Mackenzie Place.
>   Chevy Chase, Maryland.

It seems fairly apparent that this stands for

> **Customer Name and Address**

Since that's the context of the scene.